# disable ipad default resign button Xcode

Tags: ipad, default, keypad

I am working on iPad app and for textfield i have some validation like its text cant be empty if so it should display an error alert.But in iPad we have its default button at the bottom right corner of keypad which has image some what like a keyboard.Clicking on this very button the keyboard resigns automatically without any validation check
.

How i can disable the textfield resign clicking on this button.

[textField resignFirstresponder];
or 
textfieldsholdreturn  method will help ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about this, but the `textFieldShouldEndEditing:` method in `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol should be what you're searching for.

The documentation says:

> Note: If you use this method to validate the contents of the text field, you might also want to provide feedback to that effect using an overlay view. For example, you could temporarily display a small icon indicating the text was invalid and needs to be corrected. For more information about adding overlays to text fields, see the methods of UITextField.

Comment: How can i disable the default return button at the bottom right corner of keyboard ?

Comment: You should implement the method I indicated in the previous comment and return NO when you don't want the return button to resign the keyboard